# How to get the git object of a working tree file?

Tags: git

The closest I got is [this unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56870314/5623661).

For example, the working tree have the `foobar.txt` file (which is committed as well). How to, from foobar.txt, get its object id?

The idea here is to get the git object that formed the current `foobar.txt` file.

Comment: You may think a file may have only a single object attached to it; but to prove it wrong, you should test a folder/repo with .svg or .html files so git's deduplication powers can shine.

Comment: Any single file in the tree references exactly one object. One object may be referenced by multiple files (and trees in different commits).

Comment: If it behave exactly and literally as said, then how its possible when git is deduplicing files and the .git/objects/ is waaay smaller than the files present in the tree? I'm not dismissing your comment, I'm just an newbie trying to understand how to make git and file deduplication better

Comment: @DanielB also, if for some reason a single file can't reference/be referenced by various objects forming it, how can I get that single object of a specific worktree file (so I can reformulate my question)?

Comment: Maybe you should complete the [Git Internals tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain). It addresses all your questions. Objects are zlib-compressed.

Comment: I'm not only devouring this food information but it inspired me so much I'm also building a VCS right now. IPFVCS, using IPFS for content-addressable hashes! Thanks for sharing. But I still would love to get an answer here about how to get the object of a file